# Modify an http response in a protractor test

Tags: testing, protractor

I'm trying to write some end to end tests for our application's login process, but am having trouble getting my head around the best way to set up the scenario where the user needs to change his password.

When our server responds to a successful login, a user object is returned with a `changePassword` field. The client then inspects the response and redirects accordingly.

My problem is getting the test set up so that the `changePassword` field is set - what is the best approach to use?

I see my options as:

1. Have a test set up and tear-down script for the server that creates a brand new user specifically for the test run with `changePassword` flag set in the database.

   This seems like the most *end to end* approach, but is probably also the most effort & code.
2. Somehow intercept the http response in the test and modify the `changePassword` flag to be set for this test only.
3. Mock the http response completely. Using this approach is the most removed from an *end to end* test, but is perhaps the simplest?

Which is the best or most common approach? Also any general pointers on *how* to actually implement the above (particularly *1* and *2*) with protractor would be great - I'm finding it hard to conceptually get straight in my head, and hence hard to know what to search for.

I'm using **protractor** as the test framework, with **angular.js** powering the client side, and a **node** server running utilising (among other things) **express.js** and **mongoDB**.

Comment: Hello, I am on the same situation. What option did you get. Do you think the option 2 is possible (and if so, have you done some research on it) Thanks! This is driving me crazy ... :S

Comment: Yes, #2 is possible, I'll add an answer with it in now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having thought about this further, option 1 is the best solution, but is not always possible.

Option 2 is also possible, and option 3 should be avoided.

For option two, a mock module can be created like so: (coffeescript)

```
e2eInterceptors =->

  angular.module('e2eInterceptors', [])
  .factory('loginInterceptor', ()->
    response: (response)->
      # Only edit responses we are interested in
      return response unless response.match(/login/)
      # do the modifiations
      response.data.changePassword = true
      # return the response
      return response
  )
  .config(($httpProvider)->
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('loginInterceptor')
  )
```

You can then inject this module into your tests using

```
browser.addMockModule('e2eInterceptors', e2eInterceptors)
```

If you want to do this globally, you can put this in the `onPrepare` function in your protractor file, otherwise just call it when needed in tests.

Comment: I am trying to use this approach, but whenever I add a mock module, suddenly my element locators are telling me they couldn't find any elements, before the dom is loaded. The test is failing & selenium is quitting in about 1 second.

Comment: Sounds confusing, no idea where that is, probably a typo somewhere, perhaps in the module name.

Comment: I got those errors and fixed them, then it started failing like that. So its at least not those errors.

Comment: Hmmm you may have been right, I have no idea what it was but I redid it and that error has gone away. However, it doesn't seem like the interceptor is being called on the put request.

Comment: Yeah, hmm, I have it in another file with `export.e2einterceptor = function() { angular.module interceptor code here`, but that isn't getting called. Here is another issue I made for it if you'd like to help, which would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to look at the data passed through into a request.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088695/e2e-interceptor-not-working-to-peek-into-http-requests

Comment: I made a bad assumption. It was working, but within the browser of course. For some reason I was expecting it to console log to the protractor console.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first approach is the most appropriate.

It would be useful anyway to test the new user creation, so it is not a waste.
And for example this example seems to be something similar: http://product.moveline.com/testing-angular-apps-end-to-end-with-protractor.html

Comment: Actually the example you have provided doesn't match you answer. They use approach **3** from my question.

Comment: Ehh sorry. I read only until the "Basic testing" section, which is I think relevant, but you are right the "beyond the basics" section is the approach 3 as you mention.